# Apache, rewrite and .htaccess misterium

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^plugins/.* pluginLoader.php [L]
RewriteRule ^settings\.php index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.art$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /system/
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

It works, how expected, until the URL points to a name of existing file without extension situated in `plugins` directory. I don't know why. There is for example a `/plugins/invoice/name.txt` file.

```
http://localhost/plugins/invoice/name.txt
   uses pluginLoader.php as expected
http://localhost/plugins/invoice/name.
   uses pluginLoader.php as expected
http://localhost/plugins/invoice/name
   uses index.php! Why?
http://localhost/plugins/invoice/nam
   uses pluginLoader.php as expected
```

The same applies for all files having `.txt` or `.php` extension. If the file has `.sql` extension, it neither uses `pluginLoader.php` nor `index.php`. It sends *404 - not found*.

Is there some pre-processor?

What's is also interesting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^plugins/.* pluginLoader.php [L]
RewriteRule ^settings\.php index.php [L]
```

To delete last four lines makes it working. But URL `http://localhost/plugins/invoice/fill` still gets a 404 error. When the file has been renamed, the URL works.

Mystery...

Comment: The best way to debug this (since it can be specific to your system only) -- enable rewrite debugging at highest level and analyse log (I hope you are testing this on your local/dev server that has little or no traffic, otherwise log file will grow huge and is difficult to debug). http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging (that's for 2.4, if you are on 2.2 branch then http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog )

Comment: `Options -MultiViews` should fix the 'name-clash' problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace your .htaccess code with this and see if that helps:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^plugins/ pluginLoader.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^settings\.php/?$ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.art$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} /system/
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Make sure there is no .htaccess in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/plugins` directory.